# Prove that $\log_{10}(c^k)$ can start with digit $7$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

> Let $c$ be a natural number such that $c \neq 10^m, m \in \mathbb Z_{\ge0}$. Prove that we can choose some $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
> the $10$th base representation of $ \log_{10} (c^k) \ \text{starts with 7}$.

My idea was dividing value of $\log_{10}(k)$ into multiple intervals, and choosing specific $k$, we can conclude. ( For example, $9  \cdot 10^m \le \log_{10}(c) \le 10^m$,we can let $k=8$, $ |8 \cdot10^m\le \log_{10}(c)<9 \cdot10^m,$ we can let $k=88$ etc.). However, this seems pretty long and inefficient, is there any other way to proof it? Can someone give another idea to aproach?
And I think it is possible for other digits than $7$, ( except 0 ofc), and my idea is still the same.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2230226/show-that-there-are-infinitely-many-powers-of-two-starting-with-the-digit-7.  It's all based on the irrationality of $\log_{10}(c)$ for your question.

Comment: ^ and the equidistribution of $\log_{10}(c^k)=k\log_{10}(c)$, since the set $\{k\alpha \mod 1\}$ is equidistributed for irrational $\alpha$

Comment: why equidistribution implies such $k$ exists?