# The first digit and the last three digits of tower of exponents

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function, chinese-remainder-theorem

How to find the first digit and the last three digits of ${{{{2}^{3}}^{4}}^{\cdots }}^{1000}$, where the expression contains all integer numbers (from $2$ to $1000$, in order)?

Comment: https://www.exploringbinary.com/patterns-in-the-last-digits-of-the-positive-powers-of-two/

Comment: The last three digits seem easy , but the first digit is far from elementary.

Comment: @1ENİGMA1, then we need to find 3^4^...^1000 in the form $a+bk$, ($a$ and $b$ are natural numbers).

Comment: Well, it is obvious that 100 (the period of the last 3 digits) divides $3 \cdot 4 \cdot ... \cdot 1000$, hence $2^{3^{4^{... 1000}}}$ can be written as $2^{100k}$ for some $k$. According to the quoted article this means that the last 3 digits must be $376$

Comment: No @Ronald, the 4 is a power on 3, the 5 is a power on 4, and so on; not a product of exponents.

Comment: @OscarLanzi , you are right (the expression contains exponents, not a common product).

Comment: The first digit cannot be determined, the number is just too large.

Comment: @OscarLanzi so $2^{3^4}$ means $2^{(3^4)} = 2^{81}$, not $(2^3)^4 = 2^{12}$

Comment: Yup @Ronald, that's how it works.

Comment: @Peter, the expression "too large" does not mean that the first number can not be determined. For example $1000^{1000}$ has $1$ as the first digit. Not because it is obvious, but because there is a pattern for multiplying $1000 \times 1000 \times ... \times 1000$.

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari Apart from such trivial cases, there is no hope. We would need the logarithm accurate enough.

Comment: @OscarLanzi  That's a little counter-intuitive to me. If I see an expression like operand operator operand operator ... operand, with all equal operators, I evaluate it from left to right. And obviously this is correct unless the operator is the power operator. In other words the power operator is right-associative contrary to operators like +, -, *, / that are left-associative. Never too old to learn. Thank you

Comment: In binary, the first digit is 1 and the last three digits are 000.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006159/leading-digits-of-large-power-of-2

Comment: @Peter, See Barry Cipra comment, I could not understand it well, but it seems possible to find out the first digit. What do you think?

Comment: @Hussain-Alqatari The digit $1$ in binary is a joke. Concerning the first decimal digit, I guess the method tries to use some structure in the first digits of the powers of two. But there is no such structure that allows to determine the first digit of so huge powers of two. I still do not believe that the first digit can be determined.

Comment: @Peter, dear Peter, I did not mean B. Goddard comment, I meant Barry Cipra comment. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006159/leading-digits-of-large-power-of-2

Answer (score 1):

Let us compute the last three digits. Basically, we want to calculate:

$$2^{something \ big} \mod 1000$$

In general, values of $a^n$ modulo $m$ start to repeat after a certain value of $n$. For example, in case of $a=2$ and $m=1000$, values $2^1$ and $2^2$ won't appear ever again, but:

$$2^3=2^{3+100}=2^{3+2\times100}=...=008\mod1000$$

Base exponent $b$ and period $p$ can be computed for every possible value of $a,m$. I'll need a function for it:

```
findCycle[n_, modulo_] := Module[
  {n2 = Mod[n n, modulo], k = 1, lst = {Mod[n, modulo]}},
  While[! MemberQ[lst, n2],
   AppendTo[lst, n2]; n2 = Mod[n2 n, modulo]; k = k + 1;
   ];
  pos = Position[lst, n2];
  Return[{pos[[1, 1]], k + 1 - pos[[1, 1]]}];
  ]
```

For example:

```
findCycle[2,1000]
```

returns $b,p$ for $a=2$, $m=1000$:

```
{3, 100}
```

For values of $n\ge b$ we can write:

$$a^n \equiv a^{[(n-b)\text{mod}\ p]+b}\mod m$$

$$a^n \equiv a^{[(n \ \text{mod}\ p)-(b\text{mod}\ p)]+b}\mod m\tag{1}$$

Note that if the value in the square brackets is negative, we have to add $p$ to make it positive. Now suppose that:

$$a=2^{3^{4^{\dots^{1000}}}}$$

This tower is a nightmare to write, so I'll represent it as list:

$$a=\{2, 3, 4, \dots,1000\}\tag{2}$$

Replace that into (1) and you get:

$$\{2, 3, 4, \dots,1000\} \equiv 2^{[(\{3, 4, \dots,1000\} \ \text{mod}\ p)-(b\text{mod}\ p)]+b}\mod m$$

$$\{2, 3, 4, \dots,1000\} \equiv 2^{[(\{3, 4, \dots,1000\} \ \text{mod}\ 100)-3]+3}\mod m$$

Now you can repeat the same process to calculate:

$$\{3, 4, \dots,1000\} \ \text{mod} \ 100$$

With this in mind we can create a recurrent function that calculates any tower modulo any number. We'll pass the tower to Mathematica as the list (2).

First, any tower is equal to zero modulo 1:

```
findMod[tower_, m_] := 0 /; m == 1
```

If the tower has single number (no exponent at all), just calculate the module:

```
findMod[tower_, m_] := Mod[tower[[1]], m] /; Length[tower]==1
```

And in the general case, we'll have to apply resursion:

```
findMod[tower_,m_] := Module[
    {a1,tower2,cycle,b,p,exp},
    a1=tower[[1]];
    tower2=Drop[tower,1];
    cycle=findCycle[a1,m];
    b=cycle[[1]];
    p=cycle[[2]];
    exp=findMod[tower2,p]-Mod[b,p];
    If[exp<0, exp=exp+p];
    exp=exp+b;
    Return[Mod[a1^exp,m]];
]
```

We can test the recursion on a simple tower:

$$2^{3^5} = 2^{243} = 14134776..........0958208 
\equiv 208 \mod 1000$$

The following call will really return **208**, as expected:

```
findMod[{2, 3, 5}, 1000]
```

You can calculate the last 3 digits of the complete tower from the problem with the following call:

```
findMod[Range[2,1000], 1000]
```

...and the result is **352**.

The first digit of the tower is equal to the first digit of Graham's number.

(Just kidding)